# Scalar function to calculate items count?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `nvarchar` column which contains values like following:

```
item1+item2
item1+2item2
4item1+item2+2item3
```

I want a scalar function to calculate the item count.

As examples above, we notice:

- items separated by "+"
- The item may be have digit in first. This is    the item count.

The required count for above examples should be as following:

```
item1+item2           2
item1+2item2          3
4item1+item2+2item3   7
```

Comment: Fix the schema. Read ["Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad?r=SearchResults&s=1|192.8696).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option using `try_convert()` and `string_split()`

This one is assuming single digit leads.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('item1+item2')
,('item1+2item2')
,('4item1+item2+2item3')

Select * 
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select value = sum(isnull(try_convert(int,left(value,1)),1)) 
                  From string_split(SomeCol,'+') 
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
SomeCol              value
item1+item2          2
item1+2item2         3
4item1+item2+2item3  7
```

Comment: thank you for reply but I use SQL Server 2016: 'try_convert' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @yhassany 2016 does indeed support try_convert().   Try_convert() was introduced in 2012

Comment: so why this error displays? "'try_convert' is not a recognized built-in function name.
"

Comment: What happens when you run `select @@version`?

Comment: @yhassany here is a dbFiddle illustrating 2016 works   https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=3bfaa5000a72b61d0c1548d7021820d2

Comment: @yhassany  Check your compatibility level.      SELECT name,compatibility_level FROM sys.databases

Comment: Yes, either compat level is still 100, or you are using SSMS 2016 against an older engine (2005, 2008, 2008R2).

Answer (score 0):

You can split the values.  Then extract the leading number:

```
select t.*, v.the_sum
from t cross apply
     (select sum(coalesce(nullif(v.num, 0), 1)) as the_sum
      from string_split(col, '+') s cross apply
           (values (try_convert(int, left(s.value, patindex('%[^0-9]%', ltrim(s.value) + ' ') - 1
                                         )
                               )
                   )
           ) v(num)
     ) v;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=54554fb7edba2d90bfe202eff077e0b0) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  this assumes that the prefix is never explicitly `0`.  That can be handled, but adds a bit of complication that doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: thank you for reply but I use SQL Server 2016: 'try_convert' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @yhassany . . . `try_convert()` has been in SQL Server since SQL Server 2012.